# How to get an access token without an authentication to facebook?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

So what I want to do is get an access_token for my website that gets information from a public group. I dont want to authenticate with my facebook account everytime I want to see information.
Please any ideas?

Comment: Exactly what type of information are you trying to get? Some info might be accessible without access_token.

Comment: I want their public info suchs as their Posts, Name and image, problem is, it says: requires a invalid token everytime i try to access the info.

Comment: Like this:
 "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this

Comment: Took a look at groups, you do need access_tokens to query info there, i'll write answer shortly.

Comment: Problem is, I need to be authenticated to get the access_token, so everytime i wanna run my website to write out the info on the group it checks if I'm authenticated..and If I'm not authenticated I have to log in to facebook.. ( it redirect me to the facebook log in page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make graph api calls to groups, you need any valid access token. The easiest way to get one without authenticating any users is getting [App Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens) . There is an example of how to get that token in the link. Get it and use it in your calls.

Comment: Thank you!! It works now.. Tho is it ok to just write like this?:
string access_token = "my app token"?

Comment: Not exactly. Access tokens live for some period of time, so if you just copy/pasted access token from the link, it will stop working after some time.

Comment: Not sure that app token that is for a group will expire. it says only if the user change the secret id. so i think its cool :o sorry for slacky english writin xD